# Does Shadow Blend make your opponent flat-footed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, stealth

Shadow Blend from *Lords of Madness* pg 168 says:

> In any conditions other than full
>   daylight, a shadow creature can disappear into the shadows, giving it total concealment

[The SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/hide.htm) states that

> Total cover or total concealment usually (but not always; see Special, below) obviates the need for a Hide check, since nothing can see you anyway.

Since when you are hidden from an enemy he is flat-footed against your attacks

*Rules Compendium* pg 92

> If you're successfully hidden with respect to another creature, that creature is flat-footed with respect to you. That creature treats you as if you were invisible.

Does shadow blending make my opponent flat-footed?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. You being hidden in your opponent's face is very different than a rogue coming out of the wall and attacking. My main problem here is the opponent knowing where you are but not being able to see you, and you keep attacking him.

Comment: The question is the same no matter what the concealment comes from. Whether it be Shadow Blend or some other spell effect.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho This [answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37878/8610) provides such modifiers.