# Can an invisible creature use its gaze attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters, invisibility

Can an invisible creature use its gaze atack? Or, do I have to see a creature with gaze attack to be affected by its gaze? Assume the creature does not stop being invisible by attacking.

I think the answer is no, because:

> A gaze special attack takes effect when opponents look at the creature’s eyes.

But I am not sure of it.

Answer (score 10):

## Invisible creatures can't use gaze attacks

Both the *Dungeon Master's Guide* and the *Rules Compendium* say, "Invisible creatures can't use gaze attacks" (294 and 59, respectively), as does the *SRD* [here](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#gaze-attacks). It's a mystery why this fact goes unmentioned in the *Monster Manual* glossary on gaze attacks (309–10). Similarly, [darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37878/8610) may prevent a creature from using its gaze attack.

Comment: And, of course, *True Seeing* and *See Invisibility* would make you vulnerable to the gaze attack!

Comment: @MichaelW. While I totally agree that would make sense, I'm not sure that's technically the case. I mean, the game says, straight up, "Invisible creatures can't use gaze attacks," and makes no exceptions. If it ever came up, this DM'd probably side with the PCs, be they the gazers or the onlookers, but in nearly 20 years of this game, I've never had a PC or NPC that had a gaze attack turn invisible—a gaze attack is just *too big* of a force multiplier to waste that way, and I find invisibility *as a concept* an *incredible* pain in the butt to run.