# Can Listen be used to pinpoint the location of an invisible enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, invisibility, hearing

I know I will still have to deal with the miss chance from concealment, but can I use Listen to at least find which square to attack?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37878/8610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you may not be able to accurately attack where they are, that would depend on your opposed Wisdom roll. The text for Invisibility is as follows:

> A creature can use hearing to find an invisible creature. A character can make a Listen check for this purpose as a free action each round. A Listen check result at least equal to the invisible creature’s Move Silently check result reveals its presence. (A creature with no ranks in Move Silently makes a Move Silently check as a Dexterity check to which an armor check penalty applies.) ***A successful check lets a character hear an invisible creature “over there somewhere.” It’s practically impossible to pinpoint the location of an invisible creature. A Listen check that beats the DC by 20 pinpoints the invisible creature’s location.***

So you can make the check to determine that there is something there, and if you REALLY succeed, then you can make attack rolls, but those will be less likely to hit:

> If a character tries to attack an invisible creature whose location he has pinpointed, he attacks normally, but the invisible creature still benefits from full concealment (and thus a 50% miss chance). A particularly large and slow creature might get a smaller miss chance.
>
> If a character tries to attack an invisible creature whose location he has not pinpointed, have the player choose the space where the character will direct the attack. If the invisible creature is there, conduct the attack normally. If the enemy’s not there, roll the miss chance as if it were there, don’t let the player see the result, and tell him that the character has missed. That way the player doesn’t know whether the attack missed because the enemy’s not there or because you successfully rolled the miss chance.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, you can use Listen to try to pinpoint an invisible creature

The [SRD section on invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#invisibility) says:

> A creature can use hearing to find an invisible creature.A character can make a Listen check for this purpose as a free action each round. (...) A Listen check that beats the DC by 20 pinpoints the invisible creature’s location.

So although it is quite difficult, Listen can indeed be used to pinpoint a creature that is invisible.